# How can I display Biograph object on axes in matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, graph

I have interface (GUI) that contain 1 push button (Draw) and one axes

and I have biograph object :

```
gr=[0 1 0;0 1 1;0 0 0];
bg = biograph(gr);
```

and I want to display the graph in the axes that in my interface ,when I use

```
view(bg)
```

it opens new form to display graph , and I try to display it in the axes by using:

```
xx=view(bg);
plot(xx)
```

but I could not!!
Cold you help me please

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `view(bg)`, it doesn't open a regular figure, but the biograph viewer. This contains not only the display of the graph, but also several custom controls for zooming and panning the visualization, and context menus for manipulating and annotating the graph itself. The biograph viewer is designed to be used interactively on its own, rather than embedded in a user-designed GUI.

It's therefore not possible to directly/simply display the biograph in your own axes.

The best workaround I can think of is the following:

1. Have your GUI call `view(bg)`, which will bring up the display in a different window.
2. Call `set(0, 'ShowHiddenHandles', 'on')`. This is needed as the biograph viewer hides its handle from you.
3. Call `bgfig = gcf` to get a handle to the biograph viewer.
4. Get the children of the biograph viewer with `c = get(bgfig, 'Children');`.
5. Copy the biograph axis (which is the first child of the figure) to your GUI figure with `newAxisHandle = copyobj(c(1), myGUIFigureHandle)`
6. Resize the new axis `newAxisHandle` on your GUI figure appropriately.
7. Call `close(bgfig)` to close the biograph viewer.

That feels like a pretty gross thing to do, but I think it will happen fast enough that the users of your GUI should only notice a quick flicker.

Comment: I don't know what happen to my matlab , when I try to run GUI I got this error: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47824841/error.jpg this error appear for all my GUI projects

Comment: thanks

I wrote:

gr=[0 1 0;0 0 1;0 0 0];
bg = biograph(gr);
xx=view(bg);
set(0, 'ShowHiddenHandles', 'on')
bgfig = gcf;
c = get(bgfig, 'Children');
newAxisHandle = copyobj(c(1), myGUIFigureHandle);
close(bgfig);

and I got error:Undefined function or variable 'myGUIFigureHandle'.
any help?

Comment: You would need to replace `myGUIFigureHandle` with a handle to the figure of your GUI.